# Echarts for react Library, ¿Como acomodar la gráfica para que se vea correctamente desde el lado derecho?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

mi duda es la siguiente, necesito montar un gráfica donde el yAxis lo necesito del lado derecho, la documentación explica como hacer, pero la gráfica no se acomoda del lado derecho, y la documentación tampoco veo que explique como hacerlo:

Asi se ve la gráfica actualmente:
https://prnt.sc/rrorb4

Y necesito que la gráfica se acomode como lo muestra acá con lineas rojas:
https://prnt.sc/rroszx

Osea que cambio de lado, tambien a la derecha, para que se ajuste al lado derecho del yAxis. Si alguien puede ayudarme, de antemano se lo agradezco.

Codigo:

```
class RedGraphic extends PureComponent {
  getOption = () => {
    return {
      grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '8%',
        bottom: '0%',
        top: '10%',
        height: 155,
        containLabel: false,
      },
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          boundaryGap: false,
          data: ['周一', '周二', '周三', '周四', '周五', '周六', '周日'],
        },
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          type: 'value',
          position: 'right',
          splitLine: {
            show: false,
          },
          splitNumber: 2,
        },
      ],
      series: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          stack: '总量',
          data: [400, 350, 250, 200, 150, 100, 0],
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#F53939',
          },
          areaStyle: {
            color: '#F53939',
          },
          showSymbol: false,
          smooth: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="red-graphic layout-red">
        <div className="parent">
          <ReactEcharts option={this.getOption()} style={{ height: '350px', width: '100%' }} className="react_for_echarts" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has probado a pasarle los valores de `series.data` en orden inverso?

```js
data: [400, 350, 250, 200, 150, 100, 0],

to 

data: [0, 100, 250, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]
```

Comment: Funciona! fue una solución bastante simple, no se me habia ocurrido antes, gracias! Supongo que necesito pasarle los datos de manera inversa desde 0 a un numero mayor a 0 para que la gráfica tome la forma deseable, Gracias!

Comment: Así es, digamos que el índice 0 del array es la primera posición empezando por la izquierda, en este caso.